# How can I add bullet points in xd?

Tags: text, style, adobe-xd, figma, layer-style

I am trying to add bullet points in my design using **Adobe XD** but this function not available in xd,

Although I know some of trick to do it

> 1. By clicking `ALT` + 0149

> 2. Copying and pasting text already having bullet point

But the problem is, every time doing this using these 2 methods is really time consuming, is there any way to do it ??

So should I just simmply shift **Adobe Xd** to **Figma** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a free plugin for this called **Lists Plugin**, for creating bulleted and numbered lists.  It's better than just typing bullet points because there are various options in the plugin to adjust the list according to your requirments

[image]

**Basic Operation**

1. Type some text like this, using an asterisk where you want the bullet points to go

[image]

2. Open the plugin, make sure the text box is selected, and hit the Make List button. You'll get something like this, with bullet points added to the list items.

[image]

3. You can adjust the position of the bullet points by hitting the up and down arrows in the plugin. Click Apply each time to see the result

[image]

Here's the finished result

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bill, the plugin works as advertised. Unfortunately, the bullet itself is not customizable, which is pretty pathetic…